# Scroll down google maps webpage using selenium python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to collect data on a google map webpage, however i can't find a way to scroll down the page to get all the data.

I'm using python 3 and Selenium package,

thank you in advance,

Comment: Is there something you tried and did not work ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it works for me

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    
number = 0
    
while True:
    number = number+1
```

### Scroll down to bottom

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)
```

### Wait to load page

```
time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
```

### Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')

new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", ele)

if new_height == last_height:
     break

 last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to locate the element and use `browserelement.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",option)`

For example:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bengaluru,+Karnataka/@12.95396,77.4908522,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3bae1670c9b44e6d:0xf8dfc3e8517e4fe0!8m2!3d12.9715987!4d77.5945627")
option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hNLpDc-HiaYvf-DWDkFd-HiaYvf-haAclf']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",option)
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll down with selenium:

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
```

and smooth way

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });')
```