# How to scroll down google maps using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scroll down the google maps page using selenium but unable to do so. I have tried all the things written here:
[Scroll down google maps webpage using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598828/scroll-down-google-maps-webpage-using-selenium-python)

Here is my code:

```
def scroll(self):        
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = self.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight") 

    number = 0

    while True:
        number = number+1

        # Scroll down to bottom
        
        ele = self.find_element_by_css_selector('div[jstcache="211"]')
        print(ele)
        self.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 500)', ele)

        # Wait to load page

        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        print(f'last height: {last_height}')

        ele = self.find_element_by_css_selector('div[jstcache="211"]')
        
        new_height = self.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", ele) 

        print(f'new height: {new_height}')

        if number == 5:
            break

        if new_height == last_height:
            break

        print('cont')
        last_height = new_height
```

but cannot figure out how to scroll down.

Kindly help!!

Comment: Have you tried yourself ? Are you getting any error ? Can we see your code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Akzy I have added the code kindly see whats the problem

Comment: @glitch_123 Did you manage to get it work?

Comment: @askingtoomuch yes I have made it work , I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which worked for me is:

```py
def scroll(self):
    for i in range(6,25,3): 
        last_review = self.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[jstcache="192"]')
        self.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', last_review[i])
        time.sleep(5)
```

The idea behind this is that every time fetch all the business boxes and scroll into view the last one , then wait , fetch again, scroll into view the last again and so on.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers didn't work for me so this is what I came up with.

```
divSideBar=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,f"div[aria-label='Results for {query}']")

keepScrolling=True
while(keepScrolling):
    divSideBar.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    divSideBar.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    html =driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html").get_attribute('outerHTML')
    if(html.find("You've reached the end of the list.")!=-1):
        keepScrolling=False
```

"query" is just your search query, as you can see in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8ucK.png).

Comment: I hope anyone that is searching how to do this stumbles across this one as it is the only one after a heap of other attempts from various posts that actually works correctly.

Comment: This works fine for English browsers. However if your browser is in another language, it will be an endless loop

Comment: !idhem then you could target the elmeent instead:
```if driver.find_element(divSideBar, By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > div > p.fontBodyMedium > span > span'): break```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved by replacing the class name with your location:

```
results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'hfpxzc')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

After you enter the site, you will most likely have the side panel open. Close that by clicking the center of the screen once through selenium. Then send arrow keys to the map element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element(BY.CLASS, "dmCR2e widget-scene").click()
driver.find_element(BY.CLASS, "dmCR2e widget-scene").send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) 

#ARROW_UP ARROW_RIGHT ARROW_LEFT
```

Comment: Apparently "dmCR2e widget-scene" is the class of the map, it might depend on my location tho, so make sure before proceeding.

Comment: Oh yeah, also, don't forget a for/while loop if you want to scroll continuously.

Comment: I want to scroll that side panel

Comment: But there's nothing there to scroll

Comment: If you want to get something from the side panel, you don't have to scroll, because all the web elements are already on the HTML source, unless you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code and you can fix it by deleting the following lines :)

```
    if number == 5:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
sidebar_div=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="TFQHme "]')
sidebar_div.click()
no_scroll=3 # how many times do you want to scroll
for page_down in range(0,no_scroll):
    ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the end of the result search list in Google Maps, you have to change the browser language first to English. Then deactivate side bar and past this code:

```
#  scroll down in google maps with python selenium javascript
while True:
    results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'hfpxzc')
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results[-1])
    page_text = driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='body').text
    endliststring="You've reached the end of the list."
    if endliststring not in page_text:
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results[-1])
    else:
        break
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", results[-1])
```