# How to scroll down Google map reviews?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Here's the museum's reviews I would like to scrape : [url](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mus%C3%A9e+Gr%C3%A9vin/@48.8718378,2.3400264,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e66e3e9be04a55:0x7def1a3ff98df458!8m2!3d48.8718157!4d2.3422113)

Here's my script so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 


options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mus%C3%A9e+Gr%C3%A9vin/@48.8718378,2.3400264,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e66e3e9be04a55:0x7def1a3ff98df458!8m2!3d48.8718157!4d2.3422113'
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[1]/span/span/span[2]/span[1]/button').click()
#to make sure content is fully loaded we can use time.sleep() after navigating to each page
import time
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

review = []

reviews = soup.find_all('span', class_='wiI7pd')

for container in reviews:
    rev = container.text.strip()
    review.append(rev)

#print(review)


data = pd.DataFrame({
    'reviews' : review
    })

data.to_csv("test_map.csv", sep=';', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

driver.quit()
```

I read on this post that you don't need to scroll because all the web elements are already on the HTML source : [How to scroll down google maps using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543054/how-to-scroll-down-google-maps-using-selenium-python)

But in my output I just had 10 reviews.

So I would like to scroll the left panel but I don't figure it out how to do so. I tried many ways but cannot make it work.

Like this one :

```
review_box= lambda: self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to div")
review_box().click()
for i in range(19000):

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 250)")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Usually `scrollBy` always worked for me but here it doesn't work.

EDIT : This worked for me at the moment :

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

number = 0

while True:
    number = number+1

    # Scroll down to bottom
    
    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)

    # Wait to load page

    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    print(f'last height: {last_height}')

    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", ele)

    print(f'new height: {new_height}')

    #if number == 30:
     #   break

    if new_height == last_height:
        break

    print('cont')
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to scroll the element, not the window. I did it like this::

```
    public Object execJavaScript(String jsValue, Object object) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        return js.executeScript(jsValue, object);
    }

    private void scrollThroughChannels() {

        WebElement channels =selenium.findbyCssSelector("div#channels");
        long heigh = (long) selenium.execJavaScript("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", channels);

        for(int x = 0; x < heigh; x = x + 200) {
            execJavaScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = "+x, channels);
        
        ....

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is java, not python right ? How could I add this piece of code to my script ?

Comment: I would try it just like  `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById(\"channels\").scrollTop = 600")` . I am not sure, but I think the document object has no Xpath method, so use byId or byClass or something like that. You can try the scroll js in developer console in your browser (F12 -> Console). Make sure the function works standalone in your browser. Then run it in selenium.

Comment: I found a solution without java but thanks anyway :)